# Add direct link to on-topic page of help center for closed as off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic, scope

Currently the closed as off-topic questions have a banner like this:

> [image]

This banner contains two links:

- off-topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions
- help center: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help

I think that the **direct** link to what is **on-topic** (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be much more helpful for the OP, who isn't so familiar with site's subject, or even what type of questions are suitable for SE network.

Comment: Exactly! This banner is just showing the user what he did wrong but not what he can do to improve!

Comment: If anything, I would think that the link `https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions` should be on the word "Closed", not the word "off-topic".